# How to fix ShowDetail = True that does not expand details

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, xls

The following code is working well in the sense that no run-time errors are produced and pivot tables are generated with the correct data and placed at the correct place.

However, the list of items is collapsed.

Part of the code is consisting in:

- read columns heads from an array
- identify columns heads that can be placed randomnly in a range
- for each column, build a one-dimension (i.e. single field) pivot-table
- place the pivot table at a given place
- display ALL the items + their count

A) using SHOWDETAIL = True

B) recording a macro and "cloning" the code

```
For Each headerCell In wSh.Range("Ctl_Headers")
    Set sceRange = wSh.Range(headerCell.Value)
    sceRange.Activate
    fRow = sceRange.Row
    lRow = sceRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    fCol = sceRange.Column
    lCol = fCol - 1 + sceRange.Columns.Count

    Set pivCache = wBk.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, wSh.Range(wSh.Cells(fRow, fCol), wSh.Cells(lRow, lCol)))

    Set pivTable = wSh.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pivCache, TableDestination:=wSh.Range(wSh.Cells(1, nrindex), wSh.Cells(1, nrindex)), TableName:="piv" & headerCell.Value)

    pivTable.PivotFields(headerCell.Value).Orientation = xlRowField
    pivTable.AddDataField pivTable.PivotFields(headerCell.Value), "Count " & headerCell.Value, xlCount
    pivTable.PivotFields(headerCell.Value).ShowDetail = True

    nrindex = nrindex + 4
Next headerCell
```

Comment: Hence, I'm getting this: Count Ctl_Type Total
Total 11

When I'm expecting this: Count Ctl_Type 
Ctl_Type Total
Ex-Ante 1LDD 5
Ex-Post 1LDD 4
Ex-Post 2LDD 2
Total général 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `pivTable.PivotFields(headerCell.Value)` as `RowField` and the count of it as `DataField`.
You have to change following code line to address the rowfield.

Before:

```
pivTable.PivotFields(headerCell.Value).ShowDetail = True
```

After:

```
pivTable.RowFields(headerCell.Value).ShowDetail = True
```